# How else can I solve how much decaf and caffeinated coffee should go in my brew?

Tags: systems-of-equations, linear-programming

I want 39mg of caffeine in my 20oz of coffee.  blend1 has 9mg / 8oz.  blend2 has 91mg / 8oz.  it takes me 26g of coffee to produce 20oz.  assuming blend1 and blend2 weigh the same, how many grams of blend1 and blend2 do i need?

One option would be to solve for the ratio:

```
b1=9/8.0
b1=9/8.0
b2=91/8.0
g=39/20.0
t = (g - b2) / (b1 - b2)
> 0.9195121951219512195121951220
```

But what if I need 3 blends.  How else can I solve this with systems of equations or with linear programming?

Comment: interesting homework problem :) Hint: I think you should setup and equation with mg on both sides.  For example x*9/8 + y*91/8 = 39. and also x + y = 20.  that is the system for two blends.  adding another blend is just another variable.  Obviously you'll have too many variables, so you'll have many solutions.  Try setting each to zero and solving for the other two, and this will give you the corners of the solution space.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I was just trying to make some decaf coffee using the amount of regular coffee I normally consume and got interested in the problem.

Comment: Do these strange units of mg/oz and g/oz come from the land of the acre-foot?

Comment: I want to upvote you for making me laugh, but I can't.  I should have converted it all myself.  I had googled caffeine in coffee and decaf and it was all mg/oz.  I weighed the coffee I normally produce and it was 20oz.  I use 26g when weighing the beans.